# Can not log in to Management Console

Tags: jbossfuse

I have set up JBoss Fuse, created a fabric and installed the `fabric:web` feature as explained in the resource [Using the Management Console](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html-single/Using_the_Management_Console/index.html#FMCUGAccess). I can browse `http://hostName:8181` and it shows the Management Console login screen.

However, whichever user/pass combination I try, the response is "Failed to log in, Forbidden". It also shows an icon with an exclamation mark, when I click that I see the following messages appear:

```
[Branding] enabled branding
[Core] Management Console started
```

That does not help much either. How do I know what login combination I should use? It is not clear to me what I am logging into in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

In your fuse install folder under /etc there is a file called user.properties. Is the user admin with password admin filled in? If not, then at least admin user should be allowed.

If yes, try simply restarting the server. I am not sure why buy that has helped in some cases for me. Do a osgi:shutdown and then start it again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `admin/admin`?

I believe those are the default credentials.